# Cannot assign property to session object even after declaration merging

Tags: typescript, express, express-session

I'm trying to use `express-session` to save my user's login sessions, but I can't seem to add a property to the session object. I've used declaration merging to add a `user` object to the express-session like so:

```
import 'express-session';

declare module 'express-session' {
    interface Session {
        user: { [key: string]: any };
    }
}
```

And VSCode also recognizes that the `Session` has a `user` object. Unfortunately, when I try to assign a `userId` to `user`, I'm getting the following error:

`"Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'userId')"`

The assignment is done as follows:

`req.session.user.userId = user.id;`

where user.id is a number.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: That _runtime_ error means `req.session.user` is undefined. Do you expect it to exist?

Comment: I'm relatively new to typescript as well. Shouldn't I be able to assign values to user after declaration merging? Or did I miss something else? Thanks

Comment: It's a JS problem really, there is no TS in runtime.

Comment: Shouldn't `req.session.user` exist after declaration merging? I used a declaration merge to extend the `Request` object, and it allows me to assign values to the extended object. It doesn't make sense why I'm not able to do the same for `express-session`'s session object.

Comment: "after declaration merging?" --- no, typescript does not exist in runtime. You tell that it will be an object there, but you don't put it there. "it allows me to assign values to the extended object" --- if "similar" code works it only means that it's not really similar. " It doesn't make sense why I'm not able to do the same" --- then it's not the same.